# C# Visual Studio 2015 how to add button to Start new instance in a solution with several projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, customization, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution with several project and I need to launch each one of them separately. To do that I always have to right click ---> Debug ---> Start new instance.

[image]

It would be great if I could do that through custom buttons in the main toolstrip

[image]

[image]

I have seen that -perhaps- something similar could be done through adding a keyword shortcut to the project and then associate it to a button.
Is there any straightforward solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't need to launch them separately: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2015

Comment: Thanks for helping but I need to launch sometimes proj1 some other times proj5, .... and so on.

Comment: I use a custom keyboard shortcut, shift+alt+F5, to launch debug the current project `ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance`. Will launch the project containing the file I'm currently editing ;)

Comment: @Luca, if you want to debug multiple projects in the same solution at the same time, we can right click the solution name and choose Properties-Startup Project, check the Mulitiple startup projects and modify the Action or the order of each project like this doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2015, if not, it seems we can only add some buttons to 'Set Startup Projects' or 'Debug-Start new instance', cannot do them with only one buttons. Just to start new debug instance, we can use the keyboard 'shift+alt+F5' like puhzi recommended.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT thanks for the information. The problem is that most of the times I have to run only one of the multiple project. Sometimes instead I have two. But which one changes. So having buttons would help.

Comment: @Luca, as far as I know, we cannot bind 'Set Startup Projects' and 'Start new debug instance' into one button, they are two different actions, sorry for this inconvenience.